# Using VLOOKUP to populate web page views on a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm fairly new to VLOOKUP but need it for my ongoing web project.

I have two workbooks. One with a list of pages on my website (2000+) and another with web traffic stats. I want to quickly display the page views for each web page when a user clicks on it. This will fast track the content auditing process.

| PAGE TITLE | PAGE VIEWS |
| --- | --- |
| Home | Page views to display when user clicks **Home** |
| About Us | Page views to display when user clicks **About Us** |

Could you please assist in providing a VLOOKUP solution for such a task. I look forward to hearing from you. Thanks

Comment: Stop using VLOOKUP and start using the newer XLOOKUP

Answer (score 0):

I assume there are three sheets in your workbook:

1. The first holds the page's names.
2. The next one holds the stats for "Home"
3. The third sheet holds the stats for "About Us"

In the cell next to the first cell with your pagename (sheet 1) paste this formula:

```
=XLOOKUP(@A:A,sheetwithviewshome!A:A,sheetwithviewshome!B:B)
```

In the cell next to that one paste:

```
=XLOOKUP(@A:A,sheetwithviewsabout!A:A,sheetwithviewsabout!B:B)
```

Change `@A:A` for the column where the page's names are located.

Change `sheetwithviewshome!A:A` for the column where the page's names are located on the sheet with the "Home" stats.

Change `sheetwithviewshome!B:B` for the column where the stats are located on the sheet with the "Home" stats.

Do the same for the other formula.